# Compile and load a dll without saving to disk

Tags: python, clang, ctypes

I'm using dynamic code generation with ctypes, currently to load my compiled code I have to create a DLL on disk:

```
import pathlib
import subprocess
import ctypes
f = '''
#include <stdio.h>
__declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
'''

subprocess.check_output(args=('clang -shared -x c - -o lib.dll').split(), input=f.encode('utf-8'))
lib = ctypes.CDLL(str(pathlib.Path().absolute() /'lib.dll'))
lib.add.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
lib.add.restype = ctypes.c_int
print(lib.add(1, 2))
```

This is slow and wasteful since I'm never going to reuse the dll again, is there any way to load the compiled DLL directly to memory without using a hard drive?